# Unable to parse a java variable containing a number value into the Highcharts series.data

Tags: javascript, java, highcharts

I have attached my code for a javascript function that I am creating to using the Highcharts API. I am stuck at the series.data input. Everytime I try to pass in the variable staffSales in the y-value in the data array, I get an error stating that "String value sent to series.data, expected Number". I tried to change the way I pass in the data, but to no avail. Please somebody help me with this.

-- Start of Code --

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Hairstylists Sales Breakdown'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '<%= month %>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Sales($)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Sales',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [
                <%
                    List<User> users = UserDAO.retrieveStaffList();
                    for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
                        User u = users.get(i);
                        String staffName = u.getName();
                        String staffUsername = u.getUsername();
                        double staffSales = PaymentDAO.monthlySalesbyUser(m, y, staffUsername);
String salesNo = staffSales + "";
                %>
            {
                name: '<%= staffName %>',
                y: parseFloat(<%= salesNo %>) 
            },
                <% } %>
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: You can try: 
   y: parseFloat('<%= salesNo %>')

Comment: What is the value of `<%= salesNo %>` printed in your javascript? I guess it's a problem of format